# How do you select the last group in this regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to select the last group enclosed in `{}` but once I start typing `\s` at the end of the regex, it doesn't select the second line anymore. Could someone explain this to me?

Regular Expression:

```
\s*(.{10})\s*(\d*)\s*(.{3})\s*(.*?)(\((?>\((?<c>)|[^()]+|\))\))\s\{(.*)\}
```

Test Strings:

```
0.00002211      55   7.7  "'Allo 'Allo!" (1982) {A Bun in the Oven (#8.0)}
0...222.02      14   6.7  "$100 Taxi Ride" (2001)
```

Here's a link to what I'am trying to do: https://regex101.com/r/8qrKxq/2

Thanks!

---

## Update

What I expect is what happens here: https://regex101.com/r/8qrKxq/6
At `"$#*! My Dad Says"` then the first 2 series names, it grabs the right groups. But then after that somehow it screws up, I don't know how to fix this..

Comment: Update your question with sample input with expected output.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/8qrKxq/7 Why not? Your question is not clear.

Comment: Made my question more clear, if I can do anything to make it more clear, just ask me

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/8qrKxq/8

Comment: You can already see your regex failing at "SpongeyLeaks" as your format is inconsistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex expression does not include the 2nd line because it does not contain something of type `{.*}`. If you try your regex with this eg:

```
0.00002211      55   7.7  "'Allo 'Allo!" (1982) {A Bun in the Oven (#8.0)}
0...222.02      14   6.7  "$100 Taxi Ride" (2001) {9}
```

It will take the 9 enclosed in {}. If you want your selection of {} optional then you should use

```
\s*(.{10})\s*(\d*)\s*(.{3})\s*(.*?)(\((?>\((?<c>)|[^()]+|\))\))(?:\s(\{(.*)\}))?
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/8qrKxq/10)

Comment: Thanks! This works great. I'am all new to this Regex stuff so it's kinda hard sometimes. Thanks for your time and input!

Comment: Now i'am having 1 minor issue, hopefully you could solve this aswell, it now returns NULL instead of just nothing when it's empty. I'am making a parser for a database that uses .csv files. And in some titles there are , included. But now I can't use the .replaceAll(",",".") method. Because there are null pointers. So is it possible to just make an empty string when it doesn't find anything?

Comment: You can selectively use `replaceAll` for only those entries which are not null or replace all input _null_ entries as _empty string. I am not sure what platform are you using but by use of simple excel it's really easy.

Comment: Infact you can just use `\s*(.{10})\s*(\d*)\s*(.{3})\s*(.*?)(\((?>\((?<c>)|[^()]+|\))\))(?:\s\{(.*)\})?`

Answer (score 1):

> "it doesn't select the second line anymore."

All of it is on 1 line. Some lines contain `{text}` at the end and some don't.

It appears on Regex101 as if `{text}` is on second line.

Try this:

```
\s*(.{10})\s*(\d+)\s*(\d+.\d+)\s*("[^"]+")\s*(\(\d+\))\s*({[^{]+})?
```

Demo:

https://regex101.com/r/8qrKxq/9

Comment: What did you actually change an what's the implication?